# leftbarbuttonitem coming out of frame

Tags: ios

i have applied a code to add a uibutton to uibarbuttonitem and the problem is that the button is coming out of frame

the code is

```
        a1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [a1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 65.0f, 63.0f)];
    [a1 addTarget:self.slideMenuController action:@selector(toggleMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [a1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-enable-bt.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 65.0,63.0) ];
    [view addSubview:a1];

    menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];


    rootViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
```

i dont know whats wrong [image]

Comment: did u try lowering the height in the `CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 65.0,63.0)` ?

Comment: I know that it's not appropriate to say this here, but I really like the way it *currently* looks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UINavigationBar` height is 44,you set frame (0.0, 0.0, 65.0,63.0),change frame height to fit in `UINavigationBar`

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 a1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [a1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f)];
    [a1 addTarget:self.slideMenuController action:@selector(toggleMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [a1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-enable-bt.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 35.0,35.0) ];
    [view addSubview:a1];

    menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];


    rootViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try lowering the height in the `CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 65.0,63.0)` ? And yes, u are likely leaking the `view`  and `menuButton`.

Also instead of -

```
a1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [a1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 65.0f, 63.0f)];
    [a1 addTarget:self.slideMenuController action:@selector(toggleMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [a1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-enable-bt.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 65.0,63.0) ];
    [view addSubview:a1];

    menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
```

you can just give `menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:a1];` and then -

```
rootViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;

[menuButton release];
```

Comment: did so but no use .. the issue is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
UIButton * a1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [a1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 65.0f, 33.0f)];
    [a1 addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [a1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sc.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


   UIBarButtonItem* menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:a1];


    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
```

[image: sample refer here]

Comment: let me know any issues regarding this?